# Theme for settings (preferences) post lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been using `Theme.Black` on my apps settings screens (preferences) to give the dark settings screens familiar to users. Lollipop does not have dark settings screens. The apps pre-installed on the AVD have light settings screens too. Should I:

1. Just change now and stop using the dark theme.
2. Programmatically test the version of Android and only use a dark theme dark theme pre-lollipop, 
   possibly switching to option 1 at a later date. This could also be achieved by setting my own theme and basing it on different themes in a `styles.xml` file in `values` and `values-v21`.
3. Carry on using the dark theme on all devices for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app's settings screen is still part of your app, and in general you should use a consistent theme across all of your app's activities. This is especially true of Material, where color plays a large role in your app's identity.

So just use the same theme as the rest of your app.

Comment: Thank you. That rules out option 3. But should my app be in the vanguard of change on pre lollipop devices, or forms now retains dark settings so that it does not look different from all the other apps currently running on pre lollipop devices.

Comment: You ought to be using the same theme as the rest of your app on earlier versions of Android as well. What other apps are you referring to that are using a different theme for their settings?

Comment: Thanks again. I thought that there were many apps that did this, but on checking I found hardly any. I'm not sure where my mistaken belief came from. I'll remove the dark theme for settings.